# Change image color depending on background

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, jquery-svg

I need for my project to create an image object that changes colors when it is in front of another specific element and still allows me to move it around so my layout remains fluid. It is no problem if I need to have to files of the image with different colors. Could anyone tell me if this technique has a name  or point me to in some direction on how to achieve this.

Here is an example of how the effect should work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljQ0j.jpg

I was thinking of encapsulating the two images in one object along with a CSS mask for one of the images that I would try to put on the same place as my background object, but so far I haven't got a worth posting snippet of code.

Could the canvas element be of some use to achieve this, I have absolutely no experience with this element so that I don't even know if it is worth looking into it.

Thanks in advance

---

For completeness here is the solution I ended up using inpired by @ctwheels ([his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25386954/1579909)). It uses a mask object with the background image with changed colors which is positioned with the background-position property

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tchikago/1j93r9qc/)

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="myImg"></div>
        <div id="myImg2"></div>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </div>
</body>

#container {
    position:relative;
}
#myImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="220" height="210"><polygon id="triangle" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" stroke="%230038b8" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" style="fill: green" /></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#myDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:red;
}
#myImg2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="220" height="210"><polygon id="triangle" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" stroke="%230038b8" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" style="fill: gray" /></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think about to do for this, would be to write some js that would create a div with svgs with specific points based on your image, and then place your svg with those coordinates, and fill the svg with a specific fill, and the rest of the div (which would be covered with other svgs) with a different color... It's very complicated, but could work. Or better yet, a div with overflow:hidden and an svg that is the same as your image, and then change the colors

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels, I was getting the impression it would come to that, I am gonna try some tests and see if I can come up with a partially working code.

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/h1y6xxf4/2/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="myImg">
            <svg height="210" width="500">
                <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:grey;fill-rule:nonzero;" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>
        </div>
        <div id="myDiv"><svg height="210" width="500">
                <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);fill-rule:nonzero;" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}

#myDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:red;
    clip:rect(50px, 200px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

I just duplicated the image from the first div to the second and changed the background color. The second div has `position:absolute;` inside a `position:relative;` div

Comment: Thank you again @ctwheels, I am try to adapt your suggestion to my problem and come back with new feedback

Comment: Inspire by your solution, @ctwheels, I ended up doing something similar using background positioning, kind of like with CSS Sprites. I will post my solution as well for completeness. The positioning got kind of cumbersome, but since I am using Sass it was manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i can think of doing this would be using CSS filters, like saturate or hue. Still their support is not that big, and im not exactly sure how you can get it to work for what you need.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: Thanks for yout answer but I was thinking on having different images for the different colors, filters would only help with the color change, not where in the image it would happen, or am I wrong? so far in every example I saw the filter affects the whole image

Comment: You could play with filters as well as opacity to achieve something similar.

Comment: Are you sure @pablo? I think it might be possible but I would need to know the colors of the object that is gonna act as my background so I could choose the filter parameters according to my image's colors. Ideally for modularity I would like to only to have to use a reference to the object or maybe it's position